# Setting class attribute for html table in orgmode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I would like to set the class for a table in html export, e.g.:
`<table class="table table-striped">`

While it seems that setting some attributes for export of tables to HTML are possible:
`#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border` I could not find any documentation on setting the class. Is  this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can treat the class attribute the same as other attributes and just set it:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border :class striped table-striped
```

Which yielded (adding a newline for clarity):

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" rules="all" 
 frame="border" class="striped table-striped">
```

Comment: Thanks. Class was not among the set attributes so I did not think to try it.

Comment: Can I use this with standard org-mode tables? 

`#+CAPTION: title
| column A | column B |
|----------+----------|
| foo      | bar      |
|----------+----------|`